# Signal R - not load other pages

Tags: asp.net

Good day.

I have the following detail:

Make an application with signalR in vb.net (ASP.NET), which works well, the problem is that the page using SinalR has links that send me to other pages that open with a target = '_blank' in it browser, but when they open they do not load completely, when I inspect my page, the console sends me the following:

Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit while the tab is in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is foregrounded. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details

I have researched how to disable that option in chrome, I have applied it, but when opening again pages do not load.

Any ideas?

Note: My chrome is version 69.0 and in IE the pages work correctly, and the end of the page show the next message (**waiting for available socket**)